# How would I find out what day it is on an arduino without any external stuff?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Trying to find out what day it is on an Arduino without an external clock or internet.

I'm at boarding school and I'm making a program that tells me how many sleeps/days are left until Saturday (when I go home). I've understood how an LCD works but I'm struggling with finding out what day it is. I'm quite new to Arduino so go easy on the terminology :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count days from arduino start using `millis()` but if you need to countdown to specific day you have to synchronize correct date using RTC.

Code for count days from arduino start:

```
float days = millis()/1000/60/60/24;
```

Comment: millis() roll over to zero after 49.71 days

Comment: @Juraj That's true, but you can handle this if you need it in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid an Arduino, on its own, will lose track of time every time it loses power. And even when it stays powered on, the internal clock is not [too accurate](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/242/arduino-time-clock-accuracy).

The usual fix for this is to use an attached RTC (Real Time Clock) circuit powered by a button cell, such as the [Adafruit DS3231 Precision RTC Breakout](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3013?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIlpXNvbeb4AIVAb7ACh0PdAStEAQYAiABEgKf7fD_BwE)

RTCs usually have accuracy similar to typical clocks or watches.

A key part of this is the battery to keep time even when the device has power interruptions. (Also, Adafruit includes links to code for connecting to an Arduino.)

If you are willing to set the time on the Arduino pretty often (maybe off by a minute every day?), you can use a solution like this:
https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/plouc68000/simplest-uno-digital-clock-ever-4613aa

`millis()` and `delay()` will not be very accurate on most Arduinos and will be off by a few percent. Even worse, that accuracy will change depending on local conditions, such as temperature. (You could always luck out and get a great combination of board and environmental conditions for yours to be more accurate, but don't count on it.)

Comment: In my case it doesn't have to be accurate, it just needs to change how many sleeps during the night at some point. Thanks anyway